# how to find the index where the overflow occurs in the fibonacci series

Tags: java, algorithm

I have the below C code(pardon me if the syntax is not as per C language) which prints Fibonacci number of given index.It works fine.
But I have two questions here .First one is , I want to know at what index it might get overflow(assume 16 bit complier max value int data type can hold is 65535).And second one is when it overflows what values it will print for indexes after that ?

I know for my first questions it all depends on the value N, but I want to know if ther is a way I can predict for a given index n , if it gets overflowed before we calculate the Fibonacci at index n

And my last question is how do we ensure it never overflows for a given user input of value n and print correct Fibonacci value.

```
 public static int fib_loop(int n)
    {
        int[] fib = new int[n];    
        Scanf("%d",&n);
        if(n==0)            
           fib[0] = 0;
        if(n==1)
          fib[1] = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
            fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];

        return fib[n-1]; //because we only want to return for index 4 in case if n =4 :-)
    }
```

Comment: In Java, you can query "fib.length": http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html.  Otherwise, in C, you must explicitly pass the length as a function argument: `fib_loop (int n, int size)`

Comment: Suggest the max value of 16 bit is 65535.  The 24th fib is 46368
and the next is 75025.  So if you have hard coded integer sizes, use hard coded limits.

Comment: Use `BigInteger` (it is arbitrary-precision integer, which will run correctly as long as you have enough memory).

Comment: fib[0] and fib[1] should be initialized for all values n >= 2.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `unsigned` variables, overflow is well defined.  Given fib(n-1) and fib(n-2) did not overflow, fib(n) overflowed if it is less then fib(n-1).

```
unsigned fib[n];
...
fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2];
if (fib[i] < fib[i-1]) {
  ; // handle overflow
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OP says "I want to know if there is a way I can predict for a given index N , if it gets overflowed **before** we calculate the Fibonacci at index N".

Say your maximum representable number is `Big`.  In closed form:

```
r = (1 + sqrt(5))/2
fib(x) = (power(r,x) - power(-r,-x))/sqrt(5)
or
fib(x) = floor(power(r,x)/sqrt(5) + 0.5)
```

Let fib(x) be set to `Big`, and then solver for x. Then insure all your indexes are <= x.

```
static size_t FibMaxIndex = 0;
if (FibMaxIndex == 0) {
  FibMaxIndex = (size_t) (log(Big *sqrt(5) - 0.5)/log((1+sqrt(5))/2)) + 1;
}
if (index > FibMaxIndex) {
  ;  //handle too large an index
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the asymptotic ratio of terms (the [golden ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)) to predict the size of the biggest representable number:

```
int biggest = (int)( Integer.MAX_VALUE / 1.618);
for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (fib[i - 1] > biggest)
        // do something
    fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];
}
```